# Вывод значений из функции

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть функция, которая разбивает число на рубли и  копейки. И выводит это число в `tovar_price` (место в DOM  дереве). Но я бы хотел исключить `parts.join(" ")`. Тогда, получаем массив из рублей и копеек, и их нужно раскидать в разные дивы. Как быть?

```
function numberWithSpaces(x) {
          var parts = x.toString().split(".");
          parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");
          return parts.join(" ");
        }

 tovar_price.text(window.numberWithSpaces(data[0].toFixed(2)))
```

Comment: И с чем возникли трудности?

Comment: Почему не возвращать результат в виде массива, один элемент - рубли, второй - копейки?

Answer (score 2):

Если хотите убрать `parts.join(" ")` - убирайте.

```js
function numberWithSpaces(x) {
  var parts = x.toString().split(".");
  parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");
  return parts;
}

var test = numberWithSpaces(34.45);
rub.innerText = test[0];
cent.innerText = test[1];
```

```html
<div>rub: <span id="rub"></span></div>
<div>cent: <span id="cent"></span></div>
```

Comment: @Маратон Получается, что первый элемент массива - рубли, второй элемент массива - копейки.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько верный подход не знаю. Но получил такое

```
   ..........
      return {
        rub: parts[0],
        pen: parts[1]
      }
     tovar_price.text(window.numberWithSpaces(data[0].toFixed(2)).rub)
```

Comment: Такое у вас работать не должно...

Comment: Да,извините, rub - за скобку...опечатка